# How to install SWI Handler in android app

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I want to access to System Model to get Main Register ID.

Form what I learn, there should be three steps:

1. enter Supervisor mode from User mode through `SWI` instruction
2. switch to System mode by using `MSR` instruction in Supervisor mode
3. get Main Register ID in System mode by invoke the following code:

   ```
   MRC p15, 0, R0, c0, c0, 0
   ```

I want to make it happen in Android OS. Exactly, I want to get the Main Register ID when my app is running.

Now I stuck in how to install my SWI handler.

According to the [ARM doc](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/Cacdfeci.html), when I test it on Android, will create an exception.

Does someone met the same problem and solved it in the end？ help~

ps:

```
/*
 * my install handler code
 */
unsigned installHandler(unsigned location, unsigned *vector) {
    unsigned vec, oldVec;
    vec = (location - (unsigned) vector - 0x8) | 0xe59ff000;
    oldVec = *vector;
    *vector = vec;
    return oldVec;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that Android OS doesn't allow applications to install SWI handlers as this would break the security model. Applications aren't supposed to be able to run their own code in supervisor mode. Also note that he OS would likely already have a SWI handler installed to handle system calls.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is wrong in many ways.

---

Quoting the same document you linked:

> When a SWI instruction is executed, the processor enters supervisor mode

Now suppose that any application can install a SWI handler, this is equivalent of saying that any application can run in supervisor mode.
In turn this is equivalent to saying that the application is part of the OS and hence can circumvent its protections.

So J.Doe, that want to make money, writes an app that every you lock your phone it makes a call to a [premium-rate number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premium-rate_telephone_number) of him, thus draining your credit and making money.
It can do it, since the OS can do it and apps are OS, right?
Also the OS cannot stop this application as it has no more privileges.

That wouldn't be nice and that's why OSes, especially mobile OSes, have protection and a clear distinction between *user mode* and *supervisor mode*.
Application run in user mode, so that the OS can sandbox them.

---

What you were doing is also wrong from a low level point of view.
You were trying to install an SWI handler using the *load PC method*

> With this method, the program counter is forced directly to the handler address by:
>
> - storing the absolute address of the handler in a suitable memory location (within 4KB of the vector address)
> - placing an instruction in the vector that loads the program counter with the contents of the chosen memory location.

So the `location` argument (that should be a pointer, not an int) is the address where the full address of the handler is written and not the address of the handler.
But maybe you already knew that, yet there is another pitfall to be aware.

The SWI handler is unique for every possible function exposed by `swi`, the general implementation read the `swi` instruction and based on its "comment" bits jump to the correct function.
Simply put, even if it were possible to install a SWI handler, it would replace the OS one, which is no good.

---

You are probably facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), no sane users will let an app access a privileged register exactly because they are meant to be useful for system programmers only.

Some of those may contain sensitive information that are not exposed to user mode applications, if the OS decides that indeed such information can be disclosed it will offer a proper interface to read it.
Android is Linux, check the `/proc` file system and similar to see if you can find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your patience reply. It's very helpful. At the same time, I realized that my problem description may raise an XY problem. Actually, what I want to ask is to **find a way to get the Main Register ID on the ARM platform in Android App** . Before I saw your answer, I believe that the steps I described in the main content is the best way. However, it's a dead end. In the end, i still wonder whether there is a feasible way to make it happen.

Comment: @saisam what do you want to happen when your app is running on a non-ARM android platform?

Comment: @lan Cook just ignore it in this case.